# Why is Avada Kedavra considered unblockable?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

There seems to be a number of ways to block an Avada Kedavra (Physical barriers conjured by magic, hitting the spell with Expelliarmus, etc) so why do people consider it "**unblockable**"?

You just need to have quick reflexes, right?

Comment: I always thought they were saying **Avada [Cadaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadaver)**...

Comment: @Daft [They don't though](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse)

Comment: @Kevin well yeah obviously I know that now.

Comment: It's a play on words meant to sound like Cadaver + Abracadabra

Comment: @Daft Most of the spells from Harry Potter has some etymological base in real languages. There is [Pottermore article](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-etymology-of-harry-potter-spells) about that.

Comment: @TGar All that Latin gives a bit of that extra sophistication to a story about teenagers going "pew pew" with magic wands.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not truly unblockable.  What has been said is that there is "no defense against it, no counter-curse" (By the fake Moody in book 4, during his lesson on Unforgiveable Curses).  FakeMoody also says it can't be blocked, but please keep in mind that FakeMoody was a lying liar who tells lies, and things he says cannot necessarily be taken as completely honest.

FakeMoody then makes the point that no one has been struck by it and survived, save Harry.

FakeMoody lied when he said it was unblockable.  Indeed, the opposite is extremely true.  Dumbledore does clever things with statues in the Ministry, blocking killing curses.  During every major battle scene from book 5 onwards, the Death Eaters make extensive use of *Avada Kedavra*.  It, like any spell, can be blocked by physical objects (though it doesn't seem to be stopped by magical shields), it can be dodged, and (as we see in the climax of book 4) it can be struck by other spells.  Book 4's climax was, admittedly, a special case, but it does demonstrate that the Killing Curse can be affected by other magic (at least Harry's magic).

*Avada Kedavra* isn't an Unforgivable Curse because it's unblockable, it's Unforgivable because the ONLY purpose of the spell is to kill.  It can't wound, it can't incapacitate, it can only deliver death.

Comment: It's assumed that no *spell* can block Avada Kedavra nor can one reverse its effects. Dumbledore goes through the effort of Transfiguring statues and conjuring physical objects to block Avada Kedavra because a simple *Protego* wouldn't work. Note that the objects still suffer damage when taking the Killing Curse (at least one of the statues is blown to pieces) while the wizard statue reflects all manners of other spells.

Comment: The spell deflection in Book 4 is a case of what is called "Priori Incantatem", a special interaction between two "brother wands". Presumably, this would not occur in normal circumstances.

Comment: Does it really "can't wound" ? The power of a spell depends on the power of the caster, doesn't it. Would it be the same for Avada ? See : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23090/could-avada-kedavra-be-used-as-a-non-lethal-attack

Comment: @Xaltar: Look at the accepted answer for that question.  Avada Kevada isn't the 'Wound You Until You Die' curse, it's the 'Sever your soul from your body' curse.  It slays you, without a mark upon your body.  If the curse, when cast successfully, leaves no wounds to explain the death, how could an unsuccessful casting leave a wound?

Comment: @jeff It may have been figurative, but when he was demo'ing the unforgivables, (fake) moody challenged the entire class to try and use it on him GoF, and quipped that he probably wouldn't even have gotten a bloody nose.

Comment: @Sidney: Given that it can't wound, only kill, that's not a bad guess for Fake Moody.  But really, he's using hyperbole.  No teacher would expect 4th year students to master a potent (and illegal) Dark curse the very first time they try to cast it.

Comment: 'No defense' and 'unblockable' is really splitting hairs. As Slitherincess points out, it is definitely said to be 'unblockable' in *GoF*. I think there's definitely inconsistency between how the curse is treated in the books and how it is in the movies. Also, regarding the effectiveness of the unforgivable curses, Voldemort specifically says in *OotP* "You have to mean them", implying that its very possible to have an unsuccessful casting of AK, even more likely than an innocent charm e.g. *wingardium leviosa*.

Comment: @Dacio: a fine distinction is still a distinction.  And Dumbledore demonstrated in the Department of Mysteries that the Killing Curse **CAN** be blocked - he blocks it with statues.  FakeMoody was giving incomplete information.  I don't deny that you can fail to cast AK - you certainly can fail to cast it.  Unlike other spells, though, AK doesn't have 'lesser effects' at an incorrect casting.  It simply fails.

Comment: @Jeff I disagree that Dumbledore ‘blocks’ the spell with statues as such. The statues simply become the target of the spell, and it kills them quite effectively (as effectively as you can ‘kill’ a statue, at any rate). He could also have ‘blocked’ it by putting another person in front of him—basically the same effect. Actually blocking it, like with _Protego_, would mean stopping and incapacitating the spell, and that doesn’t seem possible. You can channel it into other things that are in the way, and a counter-spell can (with luck) redirect it—but it doesn’t incapacitate it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: 'putting something in front of it' is pretty much the definition of 'blocking'.  To the best of my knowledge, we never see a purely magical defense stop AK outside of Harry Potter's special defenses (brother wand and maternal love protection).

Comment: I’d say ‘blocking’ has a specific meaning when referring to spells, which is specifically to incapacitate a spell through magical means. The fact that that can’t be done with AK is basically what makes it unblockable. Otherwise the word ‘unblockable’ itself makes no sense—you can stop _every_ type of magic we ever see in the books by putting a building between it and its target.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: We never see anyone use 'block' to mean 'stop with magic only' in the books or movies.  It's used colloquially everywhere.  So far as I can tell, you are the only one who uses this novel new definition you've created ;-)

Comment: @Jeff Sure we do. Quite a few times, I'd wager. First example I can find on Google, from “Flight of the Prince” (_HBP_): »“Cruc —” yelled Harry for the second time, aiming for the figure ahead illuminated in the dancing firelight, but Snape blocked the spell again. Harry could see him sneering.« Snape certainly wasn't throwing anything at Harry or otherwise physically setting up a physical obstacle in the spell’s way—he blocked it with a counter-curse. On the other hand, I can't think of any instances where a physical obstacle is referred to as blocking a spell in the books.

Comment: My question is what was that we saw in the Goblet Of Fire movie? It was a duel with this spell ! and Harry was trying to defend!(I think at first it wasn’t Priori Incantatem cause even Voldemort didn’t get excited that it’s taking time for the spell to hit harry! I didn’t read the book and maybe it’s the problem of the movie... Can someone explain please

Comment: @FP - That was caused by the wants being brother wands used against each other in a duel.  Brother wands have this effect - when spells (possibly limited to offensive spells used in battle) collide, they link the wands.  The effect causes what we have seen in the books and movies.  We aren't told why this effect exists, only that it does.  I suspect understanding 'why' would require significant knowledge of wandlore, which none of the main characters ever pursued.

Comment: @Steam So how Harry prevented the spell when Voldemort attacked by Malfoy’s wand? (I didn’t read the books and base on the 7th movie, Harry kinda blocked that)

Answer (score 36):

Avada Kedavra is said to be unblockable in *Goblet of Fire*

> Moody raised his wand, and Harry felt a sudden thrill of foreboding.
>   ‘*Avada Kedavra*!’ Moody roared.
>   There was a flash of blinding green light and a rushing sound, as though a vast, invisible something was soaring through the air – instantaneously the spider rolled over onto its back, unmarked, but unmistakably dead. Several of the girls stifled cries; Ron had thrown himself backwards and almost toppled off his seat as the spider skidded towards him. Moody swept the dead spider off the desk onto the floor.
>   ‘Not nice,’ he said calmly. ‘Not pleasant. **And there’s no counter-curse. There’s no blocking it. Only one known person has ever survived it, and he’s sitting right in front of me**.’
>   Harry felt his face redden as Moody’s eyes (both of them) looked into his own.
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - page 191 - Bloomsbury - chapter 14, *The Unforgivable Curses*</sub>

I have a feeling someone will argue with me that this doesn't count because it was Barty Crouch Jr. as Mad-Eye Moody who said it, but *it's totally consistent with canon*. It counts.

Avada Kedavra is not a curse that can be blocked. I mean, someone could cast Avada Kedavra at someone else, yet miss (see Dumbledore and Voldemort's duel in the atrium at the Ministry of Magic in *Order of the Phoenix*). However, if the curse hits a person, that person is killed.

Comment: well said @Slytherincess

Comment: This seems to be a better candidate as the accepted answer.

Comment: The point of blocking a curse is to not be hit by it...so if the curse hits you, you didn't block it.  Your last paragraph seems like a tautology.  I'd also disagree that Fake!Moody was being entirely honest in his class.  He had a vested interest in the students NOT being able to effectively defend themselves, and giving overly-simple descriptions of the Curses that leave out important information (like being able to block AK with a physical object, even if it isn't stopped by magical shields) would be completely in-character for him.

Comment: If any spell hits a person, the effects of the spell happens even if to a lower extent. That means all spells are unblockable by your logic.

Answer (score 18):

Avada Kedavara is unblockable in the sense, **it can't be intercepted by another magic spell**. Exceptions:

- Situation of Priori Incantatem, when the caster and his opponent's wands and spells are locked together.
- Sacrificial Protection which uses magic of love.

And yes, physical barriers can block the spell. Fast reflexes can save you from this spell, <strike>but its like escaping from gun fire. Certainly, there's no Spider-Man in the Harry Potter universe.</strike>

Comment: Spells in Harry Potter are significantly slower than gunfire.  You don't have to be Spiderman to dodge them.  Similarly, we see the green bolt of AK blocked by conjured magic in the movies.

Comment: @Jeff `Avada Kedavara` looks to me like gunfire. One scene is in my mind when Voldemort tried killing Harry after he found Harry wasn't dead in the last movie.

Comment: As far as we know, the director sped up Avada Kedavra spells in the interest of being able to show the caster in one shot and the next camera angle show where it hit without having to wait for it to travel through the air.  I'd have to see the film again, but I'd be willing to bet that the speed varied greatly throughout.  My guess is that the speed of the spell is largely based on camera angle.

Comment: @Neil - [My answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/30814/656) is sourced from the books.  It isn't perfect, but I think it's a reasonable ballpark.

Comment: If it is similar to gun fire it's more like old musket fire, not modern ammunition.  Slow and innacurate to a degree.

Comment: @Monty129 : "old musket fire" was not much slower than modern ammunition. The reload time was longer, but the bullet traveled fast enough to not be dodgeable. Spell speed is more similar to bow/crossbow speed or even slower.

Comment: @vsz I guess I was trying to draw comparison to its accuracy more than the velocity.

Comment: @Monty129 : that muskets were hilariously inaccurate that you couldn't hit the broad side of a barn is a myth. Yes, without rifling, musket balls would lose energy and accuracy after flying for ca. 100 meters, but up to that range they were deadly accurate.

Comment: In the books, even during the Battle of Hogwarts, people manage to dodge the Killing Curse a considerable amount of times. Gun fire is impossible to dodge because of the speed of the projectile. So I completely agree with @Jeff - Spells in Harry Potter are way slower than muggle gun bullets.

Comment: What's the point of the strike through?

Answer (score 5):

A Shield (protego or non-verbal) charm will not stop it is probably what Moody meant by 'block', and no known counter-curse will reverse it .

Defenses seem to be:

1. Interrupt the caster before completing the spell--hit the caster with a quicker spell or folding chair
2. Disapparate -- Dumbledore did this in the Death Chamber, didn't he?
3. Priori incantatum -- this just happens, not really a tactic
4. Use a physical barrier, conjured, "animated" or existing (hide behind a pole), to stop the "jet"
5. Another living being gets between the caster and the target-- conceptually the same as a physical barrier.  Fawkes  reacted quickly enough to "take the jet" to save the intended target, right? He "swallowed"  the entire jet.  This implies you could possibly pull someone into the way if you react quickly enough, if they block the entire jet.  Regarding "sacrificial protection" -- my interpretation of the book was 3 separate AV spells were cast-- Voldemort cast AV, and killed James downstairs.  Then, he went upstairs, and told Lily to step aside.  She didn't, so he cast AV again which killed Lily, Then, he cast another AV against Harry, which rebounded because of the sacrifice.  Movie showed it differently.  Maybe I misinterpreted (or misremember) the book.  I think it is unclear whether AV can kill more than one victim, if both were somehow struck by the jet.  The movie shows it billowing out like flames from a flame thrower-- the book seems to indicate more of a focused beam, right?
6. Caster "misses".   Didn't Voldemort miss Dumbledore in the Death Chamber?  Since a "miss" is possible and it's 6 syllable curse--you have a half second or better, implying you could do one of the following

   - Duck
   - Run
7. Outlier reason-- wand allegiance. This one is beyond me, and maybe the movie is clouding my memory.   AV from the elder wand "killed" Harry in the Forbidden Forest, but not at Hogwarts-- Harry's expelliarmus stopped it cold.  Anybody?  I guess in the Forest,  Voldy killed the part of him that was in Harry, not Harry himself.  That's pretty corny.

Comment: In the Forest, Harry _meant_ to be killed. He was master of the Elder Wand, and it acted according to his wishes/plans. AK kills you by ripping your soul from your body; the limbo at King’s Cross was Harry deciding which of the two souls housed in his body would be severed, and which would remain in the body. In the castle, being killed (again) was not part of his plan, and the Elder Wand again acted according to its Master’s wishes. Or at least didn’t work well enough to cast an AK against its master that was strong enough to withstand even a simple _Expelliarmus_.

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of a folding chair as a legitimate spell defence

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is described as unblockable is that the use of the shield charm is ineffective against a killing curse, as explained by fake Alastor Moody in Goblet of Fire. You can, however, protect yourself by summoning physical shields like Dumbledore did in the Battle of the Ministry of Magic. I must also point out that powerful wizards can cast non-verbal spells, including spells like expelliarmus so this negates the fact that spells take time to cast.

Answer (score 1):

Think of Avada Kedavra as a death ray beam gun with shield piercing capabilities. If it hits, you die; armor can't protect you and shields (short of a sacrificial spell) can't deflect it. The only way to survive it is to not get hit by it in the first place, but because it's line-of-sight and *very* fast that means that much like firearms you have to dodge the caster, not the spell itself.

The big issue with countercursing is the same thing -- if it hits, it's instantly fatal. No middle ground, no injury, just death... and the incantation is a mere *six syllables long*. As Aditya points out in their answer, it takes roughly five seconds or less to cast, which puts a rather narrow maximum cap to what you can do about it.

(Research in countercharms is further hampered by the fact that there's only one way to test whether a possible counter charm would work and you don't get to try again if the answer turns out to be "Nope, doesn't work". Hope you left good notes for your successors...)

Technically, "Expelliarmus" could be considered an effective counter (can't cast the curse without a wand in your hand) but even if you assume instantaneous effect, if you aren't aren't already pointing your wand and casting by the time you hear the "va" syllable, *you'll be dead before you finish casting*.

In anything short of a straight-up face-to-face duel, that means you have roughly one short spoken syllable's worth of time to realize someone is about to murder you and that you need to get your wand up and out **now** or it won't matter anymore. That's on the order of half a second or so (try it yourself) and that's *before* we take into account the time it takes for the sound to reach your ears and your nerve impulses to draw and cast reach your limbs, lungs and vocal chords...

... I suppose taken in a purely tactical context both "reducto" and "Crucio" would be even more devastatingly effective because they require half as many syllables to cast and someone with body parts (possibly vital ones) missing or writing on the ground in incapacitating pain isn't going to be able to defend themselves against your follow-up any time soon, but both of those are survivable if  help arrives in time (well, unless reducto took your head off).

Avada Kedavra is not. That's why it's considered so damn scary, why it's one of the Unforgivable Curses, and why Harry's survival is regarded as a Big thing.

(Side note: "Reducto" would be a better counter to AK than Expelliarmus because it takes two less syllables to cast so you have a wider window, but you'd have to make sure to hit either their wand arm or their head to prevent them from finishing the curse, so...)

Answer (score 0):

As stated it has never been specifically said as unblockable.However it has been infered there is a specific limit of spell protection in the potterverse as demonstrated in the weasley's profitable hats,cloaks and gloves which have been comfirmed that they only work well against minor offensive spells unlike major jinxes and curses.

From this it can be infered that 'the killing curse' with holds much penetrating power which is capable of destroying shield charms however not much can be said if another offensive spell intercepts the curse head on such as the expelliarmus

Answer (score 0):

There is no counter curse to the Avada Kedavra (Expelliarmus only worked for Harry because his wand was twined with Voldemort's and could not be forced to do battle with each other).
Yes physical objects can be moved into the path, but this is not a counter curse and it takes an extremely skillful wizard to do so quicker than the curse - particularly in a life and death situation.

The only direct magical defences are Horcruxes; which if you have one (or more), will keep your soul earthbound even after your body dies. Or "Self-Sacrifice"; if someone willingly takes an Avada Kedavra curse, without trying to defend themselves, to protect someone else (as Harry's mother did for him and as Harry himself did for all his friends at the end of *The Deathly Hallows*) then the person who was protected cannot be touched by the wizard who cast the Avada Kedavra. Any curse they attempt to cast on them will be unbinding and another Avada Kedavra will be rebounded.
This is what happened the night Voldemort tried to kill Harry in Godrics Hollow, Voldemort only survived because of his Horcuxes.

Answer (score -1):

Avada Kedavra can be dodged. It can be blocked physically or with spells. But once it hits you, you can't stop yourself from dying.

Comment: This just repeats earlier, more detailed, answers.

Answer (score -1):

What Moody ment it is that it is  not reversable. If you are hit by avada kedavra there is no counter curse to reverse it effect. Also it feels like he mean that it obviously penetrate any protective charm or something like that.  What is my problem its that sources says that it cant be cast withou incantation. That means u cant cast it without saying loud avada kedavra yet in movies it looks like nothing - lriory to make fights dynamic but i just do not like. But I think if you hit avada kedavra spell with your spell its like magic energy versus magic energy and it somehow disrupts ewch other or rebounds. Avada can destroy surface when it miss target or rebound from surface.

But there is protection from avada. Horcrux

Comment: This is given in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

It is strange that nobody tries blocking it with conjured items or even summoning bricks or some junk in the path of the spell. I think unblockable means that it just pases the shield as it wasn't there.

Comment: Not strange at all, since that’s exactly what Dumbledore does at the Ministry of Magic.

Comment: Most people aren't quick or calm/confident enough to do that.

Comment: Also, this isn't actually an answer, it's more of a comment.