# What happens if I miss with a spell?

Tags: harry-potter

If I miss someone with a spell, does that spell continue travelling indefinitely until it hits something and dissipates?

The Avada Kedavra spell for example, that's [unblockable](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32327/20393) right? Would that travel further than any other spell?

Comment: I don't recall if it happens exactly this way in the books, but in the movies, at least, I seem to remember a lot of spells missing during battles and hitting the environment (rocks, walls, etc) and smashing them and then stopping. But they were always close to the target.

Comment: @phantom42 those exact instances are what made me ask this question. Alas, it's a dupe of a unanswered question asked years ago.

Comment: In OotP(Book) they miss spells in their DA lessons.
In their first lesson they're trying to learn Expelliarmus but instead of disarming they miss and hit the bookshelfs and books are flown of the shelfs. Does not really answer your question, but missed spells do exist in the books too.  But like phantom42's example rather close to target I assume.

Comment: @ThomasDB but the spells probbaly just hit the floor or  wall right? I want to know what would happen if they never hit anything. Would they travel on forever?

Comment: I elaborated my comment a bit(pushed enter too fast), but it's rather a comment on phantom42's comment. But my instinct says no. In the end even magic is affected by the laws of physics, but there's no canon answer for this. Unless you could ask JKR. But as in universe, it would be a bad situation i'm afraid if it were to travel on forever

Comment: Seems to me that if an accurate spell has a range, a missed spell would share that range.