# Why WOULD Moody get a nosebleed?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, avada-kedavra

When fake-Professor-Moody is telling about Avada Kedavra, he says that if they all point their wands at him and say the words, he doubts he would "*even get **as much as a nosebleed***"

Why *would* he get a nosebleed? The Avada Kedavra spell doesn't (normally) leave any physical marks, as he is evidently aware.

> The exception sits before me.

Comment: Related to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23090/could-avada-kedavra-be-used-as-a-non-lethal-attack?rq=1

Comment: Maybe he was just [quite excited](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Nosebleed)

Comment: @Valorum you should have written "Warning: TVTropes"!

Comment: @A.Darwin - See you in an hour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think he literally meant it.

It is known since PS/SS that the Killing Curse normally doesn't leave any kind of physical mark, and most students knew it by the beginning of the 4th year.

It is not clear [what kind of damage the Killing Curse does](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65638/what-type-of-damage-does-avada-kedavra-do).

If AK damages or rips the soul, Moody should have said

> you could all get your wands out now and point them at me and say the words, and I doubt I’d get so much as a one tenth of my soul damaged.

which is an odd statement, and wouldn't have conveyed in the same way the idea of AK requiring magical strength in order to work.

If AK kills by stopping all bodily functions, Moody should have said something like

> I doubt I’d get so much as a brain cell not working.

If there is another mechanism, someone should have explained it in advance, and Moody's example would have likely been more complex to understand.

Comment: +1, but I would suggest a modification: I don't think AK *damages* the soul, since in HP verse "damaging the soul" refers to people harming themselves with evil, not people being harmed by others' evil. Being hit by AK kills one, but doesn't damage the soul of the affected party but rather the soul of the murderer.

Comment: @kviiri I know. I was actually thinking about [the type of damage AK actually does](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65638/what-type-of-damage-does-avada-kedavra-do), which is not well known. If you find out a canon proof that AK doesn't cause death by damaging the soul, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Do you have a canon source that it *does* damage the soul?